# Inflating a RecyclerView inside a Dialog layout

Tags: android

In my activity, on click of a button I am opening a Dialog which has a RecyclerView in it.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MyActivity.this);
dialog.setTitle("Details");
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.details_popup);
RecyclerView detailsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.detailsRecyclerView);
Button detailsCloseButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.detailsCloseButton);

//feedbackResponseSubList contains n items

**DetailsAdapter detailsAdapter = new DetailsAdapter(R.layout.detail_item, feedbackResponseSubList);
detailsRecyclerView.setAdapter(detailsAdapter);**
detailsCloseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
dialog.show();
```

The close button is visible but the recyclerView is not getting populated with data. Even the methods **onCreateViewHolder(), onBindViewHolder() and getItemCount()** of Detailsdapter are not getting called.

Answer (score 3):

I have figured out the problem. After setting layout manager in recyclerview, it works fine.

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(dialog.getContext());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        detailsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `Dialog` is already created when you try to modify the adapter, because of that It's not getting populated with your data.

You have two options, create your `own Dialog` which extend `Dialog` class and in `onCreate()` put your code to populate the list or add `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after `setAdapter()` to tell that your data inside the list was updated.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dialog fragment instead of Dialog. An dialog fragment gives all the features of a dialog while providing the functionality of a fragment.

```
public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

     @Override
     public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      //inflate layout with recycler view
     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_popup, container, false);
     RecyclerView detailsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.detailsRecyclerView);
     DetailsAdapter detailsAdapter = new DetailsAdapter(R.layout.detail_item, feedbackResponseSubList);
     detailsRecyclerView.setAdapter(detailsAdapter);
     detailsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
     return v;
 }

 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
  //The rest of the code you will get when u search for dialogfragments
```